# Merge tags [nelmioapidocbundle] and [nelmio-api-doc]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) is a bundle for the framework Symfony that generates documentation for a REST API from annotations.

Currently (as of today 2018-11-08) there are two tags that refer to this bundle:

- [nelmio-api-doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio-api-doc) with 54 questions
- [nelmioapidocbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmioapidocbundle) with 8 questions

There are 3 questions that are tagged with both tags. This would be easy to manually edit, if needed.

Generally the tags for Symfony bundles are concatenated from the name of the provider, the name of the bundle, and the word bundle.

Example:

- provider: FriendsOfSymfony (FOS)
- bundle: REST

Stack Overflow tag: fosrestbundle

In order to follow the already established naming convention I suggest to merge these tags under the name [nelmioapidocbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmioapidocbundle).

Having both of them is redundant, confusing and bloats unnecessary the amount of available tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updating post history, 9 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 8 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 5 rows affected
destroying 'nelmioapidocbundle': [nelmioapidocbundle] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 60
tag remapping of [nelmio-api-doc] and [nelmioapidocbundle] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym nelmioapidocbundle -> nelmio-api-doc was approved!
```

Swapped synonyms afterward,

```
updating post history, 64 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 60 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Master tag 'nelmioapidocbundle' doesn't exist, renaming to 'nelmio-api-doc'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [nelmioapidocbundle] and [nelmio-api-doc] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. However this is not exactly what I proposed. I'm sorry if my explanation was not clear. I think we should keep `nelmioapidocbundle`, delete `nelmio-api-doc` and retag all questions from `nelmio-api-doc` to `nelmioapidocbundle`. You have almost done the job, would it be possible to apply these changes too?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I should have followed the actual bundle name. The search results are cached, and should update shortly.

Comment: Great! Now it looks very neat. Thank you again.

Comment: There is also a similar issue addressed with a new [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376379/create-tag-nelmiocorsbundle-and-merge-the-tags-nelmio-and-nelmio-cors-into).