# Create tag [nelmiocorsbundle] and merge the tags [nelmio] and [nelmio-cors] into it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) is a bundle for the framework Symfony that adds CORS headers support.

Currently (as of today 2018-11-08) there are two tags:

- [nelmio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio) with 21 questions
- [nelmio-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio-cors) with 4 questions

There are no questions with overlapping tags.

The name [nelmio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio) is very confusing, as it is the name of the company, provider of the bundle. Nelmio provides few bundles for Symfony, so this is very ambiguous. The name [nelmio-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio-cors) is on the other side more descriptive, yet doesn't follow the already established naming convention for tags referring to Symfony bundles.

I suggest to have a tag with the name [nelmiocorsbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmiocorsbundle) and retag all questions tagged with the aforementioned tags.

This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376376/merge-tags-nelmioapidocbundle-and-nelmio-api-doc) has addressed a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've renamed [nelmio-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio-cors) > [nelmiocorsbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmiocorsbundle)

You can help review the questions with [nelmio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio), and see if they should be retagged into [nelmiocorsbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmiocorsbundle) or [nelmioapidocbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmioapidocbundle)

---

In future, you can link to tags like how I did above by using this format in the editor:

```
[tag:nelmiocorsbundle]
```

Comment: Thanks! There are not many of them, so it shouldn't be difficult. I'll check them all, one by one.

Comment: I've cleaned everything. Now there are no more questions tagged with [tag:nelmio]. This tag is now obsolete and its tag wiki should belong to [tag:nelmiocorsbundle].